# How to call a method within a `signal` block?

Tags: signals, raku

Is it possible to call a user defined method within a signal block?

```
method my-method ( ... ) {
    signal(SIGTERM,SIGINT,SIGQUIT,SIGHUP).tap( -> $sig {
        say "Received signal: $sig";
        self!restore-term();
        exit;
    } );
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but there are caveats.

`signal` provides a `Supply` of events, which you can `tap` (if you like to) but probably should be using inside a `react whenever` structure.

In your example, the `tap` takes a `Block` (lambda).  Every time you call the method, it will set up another `Supply` (which is probably not what you want).

This block gets called whenever an event arrives.  This means it is completely asynchronous and has no context, other than the lexical context in which the block was created.

So whenever a signal arrives in the `Supply`, it will run the block with the `self` at the moment the method got called.  Which may not be what you expect?

So it feels to me you're asking the wrong question.  Apparently you have an object (hopefully a sentinel) that you wish the `restore-term` method to be called on whenever someone indicates they want to leave the program.  So you're probably better of restructuring your program to something like:

```
my $sentinel = class.new(...);
react {
    whenever signal(SIGTERM,SIGINT,SIGQUIT,SIGHUP) -> $sig {
        say "Received signal: $sig";
        $sentinel.restore-term();
        exit;
    }
    # .... other stuff
}
```

Comment: "Apparently you have an object (hopefully a sentinel)": does this mean I should not use the main object for the `restore-term` method but create a separate object for the `restore-term` method or is a sentinel object something special?

Comment: "sentinel" in this context that it is an object waiting to have a method called on.  And yes, you can have as many `whenever` blocks as you want inside a `react`.